# Are $3^{2k}-3^k+1$ and $3^{2k}+3^k+1$ ever prime powers at the same time?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Let $q=3^k$ with $k\geq 2$.  I'd like to know whether $q^2-q+1$ and $q^2+q+1$ are ever prime powers at the same time.

I've checked up to $k=50$, and it seems that the total number of prime divisors of $q^2-q+1$ and $q^2+q+1$ is increasing, but I don't know how to prove this.

Any help/references appreciated!

Comment: The growth rate is around $9^k$ , so we won't observe much such pairs of primes.

Comment: A case that can immediately be ruled out is $k$ even. If $k=2t$ then 
$$3^{2k}+3^k+1=(3^{2t}+3^t+1)(3^{2t}-3^t+1)$$ is a product of two obviously coprime integers.

Comment: If $5\mid k$, then we have the polynomial factorization (from cyclotomy)
$$x^{10}+x^5+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^8-x^7+x^5-x^4+x^3-x+1)$$ with the latter factor equal to $\Phi_{15}(x)$. Long division shows that 
$$\Phi_{15}(x)\equiv -5x\pmod{x^2+x+1}.$$
Plugging in $x=3^{k/5}$ it again follows that we have factored $3^{2k}+3^k+1$ into a product of two coprime integers ($5$ is obviously never a factor). May be this way we can rule out all possible prime factors $p\neq3$ of $k$? The prime $p=3$ is an exception because factorizations of cyclotomic polynomials won't help when $k$ is a power of three.

Comment: Upto $k=3\cdot 10^4$ , neither expression is a perfect power and the second expression only prime for $k=1$ and $k=3$.

Comment: If $p>3$ is a prime, it seems to me that in the factorization
$$x^{2p}+x^p+1=(x^2+x+1)\Phi_{3p}(x)$$
we have that $\Phi_{3p}(x)$ is congruent to either $p$ or $-px$ modulo $x^2+x+1$ depending on the residue class of $p$ modulo $6$. So if $k=pk'$, plugging $x=3^{k'}$ into the equation we have factored $3^{2k}+3^k+1$ into a product of two integers with $\gcd\in\{1,p\}$. This may still help, but won't be enough :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen In fact , upto $k=10^7$ , there is only then no prime factor of $9^k+3^k+1$ below $10^5$ , if $3^7\mid k$. So, maybe , we can prove that $9^k+3^k+1$ is never prime for $k>1$. That would bring us near a complete solution. I think , you have a promising approach.

Comment: Thanks for all of these comments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With $q = 3^k$, assume $q^2 - q + 1 = q(q-1) + 1$ is a [prime power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_power), i.e., for some odd prime $p$ and integer $m \ge 1$, we have

$$3^k(3^k - 1) + 1 = p^m \;\;\to\;\; 3^k(3^k - 1) = p^m - 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

The following shows there are insufficient factors of $3$ in $p^m - 1$ for any $m \gt 1$.

If $m$ were even, say $m = 2n$, then

$$3^k(3^k - 1) = p^{2n} - 1 = (p^n - 1)(p^n + 1) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since $\gcd(p^n - 1, p^n + 1) = 2$, then $3^k \mid p^n - 1$ or $3^k \mid p^n + 1$. In the first case, $p^n - 1 = j(3^k)$ for some integer $j \ge 1$. However, then $p^n + 1 \ge 3^k + 2$, so the RHS of \eqref{eq2A} would be greater than the LHS. With the second case of $p^n + 1 = j(3^k)$, if $j = 1$, then $p^n - 1 = 3^k - 2$, so the RHS is a bit smaller than the LHS. Otherwise, with $j \gt 1$, the RHS is then considerably larger than the LHS.

Thus, $m$ must be odd, so then $p \equiv 1\pmod{3}$. In addition, $q^2-q+1=\frac{q^3+1}{q+1}$, so $q^3\equiv -1\pmod{p}\;\to\;q^6\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Since $q$, $q^2$ and $q^3$ are not congruent to $1$ modulo $p$, then $6$ is the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $q$ modulo $p$. Thus, $6\mid p-1\;\to\;p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$. A third method is that, from $4p^m = 4q^2 - 4q + 4 = (2q - 1)^2 + 3$, we have $-3$ being a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $p$, so the [supplements to quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#Supplements_to_Quadratic_Reciprocity) also shows $p \equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Next, the [Lifting-the-exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma) gives that

$$k = \nu_3(p^m-1) = \nu_3(p-1) + \nu_3(m) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

For some positive integers $s$, $t$ and $u$, where $3 \nmid s$ and $3 \nmid u$, plus integer $v \ge 0$, we have $p-1=2s(3^t)$ and $m=u(3^v)$. From \eqref{eq1A}, $3^k$ is just a bit more than the square root of $p^m - 1$, so it's very close to $p^{m/2}$. Thus, since $2 \approx 3^{0.6309}$, then using an exponent of $0.5$ is more than conservative enough for the $p^{m/2}$ approximation. Thus, even with $s = 1$, then $k$ is more than $\frac{(t + 0.5)u(3^v)}{2}$, but \eqref{eq3A} shows it's actually only $t + v$, so we require

$$t + v \gt \frac{(t + 0.5)u(3^v)}{2} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

If $v = 0$, then $u = 1$ gives $m = 1$, so \eqref{eq3A} has $k=\nu_3(p-1)$, which means $t = k$ and $2s = 3^k - 1$. Otherwise, if $u \ge 2$, then \eqref{eq4A} becomes $t \gt \frac{(t + 0.5)u}{2} \ge t + 0.5$, so this is not possible.

For $v \gt 0$, then \eqref{eq4A} is only true for $t = 0$ and $u = v = 1$, but $t \ge 1$, so this isn't allowed.

This proves that \eqref{eq1A} can only be possibly true for $m = 1$, with a similar argument also applying to $q^2 + q + 1 = q(q + 1) + 1$. Note [Peter's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4761274/are-32k-3k1-and-32k3k1-ever-prime-powers-at-the-same-time/4761339?noredirect=1#comment10109115_4761274) indicates that, for $2 \le k \le 4\cdot 10^4$, then $q^2 - q + 1$ is not a prime power (although it's $73$ for $k=2$), while $q^2 + q + 1$ is a prime at just $k = 3$, which gives $757$.

---

Thus, $q^2\pm q + 1$ can only possibly be prime powers if they're prime. As [Jyrki Lahtonen's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4761274/are-32k-3k1-and-32k3k1-ever-prime-powers-at-the-same-time/4761339#comment10109093_4761274) indicates, if $k = 2a$ for some integer $a$, then $3^{2k} + 3^{k} + 1 = (3^{2a} + 3^a + 1)(3^{2a} - 3^a + 1)$, so it's not prime. Thus, we'll only consider odd $k$. As [Jyrki's other comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4761274/are-32k-3k1-and-32k3k1-ever-prime-powers-at-the-same-time#comment10109137_4761274) shows, consider a prime $r \gt 3$, so it's of the form $r = 3b_1 + 1$ or $r = 3b_2 + 2$. Then, for any integer $x$, with $c_1 = x^2 + x + 1$, we have $x^3 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{c_1}$. Thus, with the first form of $r$, we get $x^{2p} + x^p + 1 \equiv x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{c_1}$, while the second form gives that $x^{2p} + x^{p} + 1 \equiv x^4 + x^2 + 1 \equiv x + x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{c_1}$. So, if $k = rk'$, then $x = 3^{k'}$ gives that $3^{2k} + 3^k + 1$ can be factored into the product of two integers, each $\gt 1$, so it's *not* prime.

Similarly, replacing $x$ with $-x$, we get with $c_2 = x^2 - x + 1$ that $x^{2p} - x^p + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{c_2}$. Alternatively, we have $x^3 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{c_2}$. Thus, with the first form of $r$, we get $x^{2p} - x^p + 1 \equiv x^2 - x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{c_2}$, while the second form gives that $x^{2p} - x^{p} + 1 \equiv x^4 - (-x^2) + 1 \equiv -x + x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{c_2}$. Using the same substitutions as above gives that $3^{2k} - 3^k + 1$ is also not prime. Thus, for odd $k$, this shows that $q^2 \pm q + 1$ can *only* possibly be prime when $k$ is a power of $3$.

I'm unsure how to proceed further to prove or disprove that $q^2 \pm q + 1$ can both be prime simultaneously. Nonetheless, due to the requirement that $k$ be a power of $3$, they will both be prime for the same $k$ at the most very infrequently, with the smallest such example likely being for a rather large $k$ value.

Comment: Very nicely done! You assume that $m>1$, but I can't see the proof failing if $m=1$ so $p^m$ is prime. Is that right?

Comment: @ChockaBlock Thanks for the compliment. I assumed that $m \gt 1$ because I've read and seen that perfect powers of integers means the power is $\gt 1$. However, the Wikipedia article I now link in the answer indicates that "prime power" *does* include just primes. I've thus adjusted my answer to accommodate that, including how that case can occur, as well as his comment results which indicate that $q^2+q+1$ is a prime for $k=3$.

Comment: Thank you for the edits! :)

Comment: @ChockaBlock You're welcome. FYI, I've just posted another edit, where I've made a small correction (i.e., q^2+q+1, with $k=3$, is $757$, not $37$). I've also added several details, in particular to show that $q^2\pm q+1$ can both be prime *only* when $k$ is a power of $3$. This significantly restricts the possibilities, but I don't know how to proceed any further than that.